# Blank response for soft layer object filters when resources are present

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have the following python script:

```
import SoftLayer
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username="XXXXXXX", api_key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
resp = client.call('SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account', 'getAllObjects', filter={'id': 56398353})
print response
```

But this always gives me a blank array.

Without the filter I get proper response:

```
[{'username': 'XXXXXXX-10', 'id': 56398353, 'accountId': XXXXX}, {'username': 'XXXXXXXXX-11', 'id': 69259064, 'accountId': XXXXXX}]
```

But the id is there in the response. Why these filters are not working? Any clue please?

I also tried:

```
resp = client.call('SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account', 'getAllObjects', filter={'credentials': {'username':'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following object filter structure:

```
object_Filter = {"id":{"operation":11111}}

resp = client.call('SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account', 'getAllObjects', filter=object_Filter)
```

Comment: This worked! Though I did not understand why the earlier one did not work. Filtering based on local attributes (topmos object's properties) use this format is it?

Comment: Yes, the filtering based on local attributes use this format and the "operation" comes by design. In the following link you can see more information about filters: https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters/